# Fill the View Controller with elements/objects from web/cloud swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have a `TableViewController` which is connected to a empty-"template" `viewController`. I would like to make each cell responsible for its own interface/design. 
In other words: the `viewController` has all elements placed (like `UIImage`, `UILabel`, `UIText`, etc.) and each time when specific cell is selected the `viewController` starts to fill with specific images/resources. Moreover, it would be great if the resources will be taken from web or cloud (in order to not save everything in the application itself).

So, I imagine it somehow like this:

[Flow sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbV30.jpg)

The problem is that I deal with this for the first time, and tried to find different ways to solve this problem (in terms of implementation), therefore I would like to ask: does this idea can be implemented in this way or probably there is more reliable way, and which techniques or technology can be used for this realization?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple approaches. It totally depends on the architecture you have been following.

You can use react/ key-value observing and set the keys when you get a response.

Alternatively, for a very small app or a POC, I would use alamofire as my network manager and as soon as I get a response, I would set the labels. I would use the image extension in alamofire to set the images as it takes more time to download.

I would want to know the exact problem you are facing to help you out. Generic discussion are not normally encouraged here.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I can explain from the other way, hope it can help:) In order to not make each cell responsible for each ViewController (i mean, not have thousands of Views in app) I want to have one single view which will fill itself according to requested cell. For ex, I could have 10 "folders" with element interfaces and when I request the specific design (cell click), the ViewController uses the resources from that specific "folder". And I want to have these "folders" on the web or cloud

Comment: it would still be only one controller. You would just change the image associated with the folder. you dont need 100s of controller.